# Is there an explicit performance benefit in shorter code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, runtime, execution

Condensing code in Python can be very helpful. It often omits multiple characters, perhaps even multiple lines in some cases, and is absolutely essential in code golfing. However, does this shortening of code have any effect on performance? Is there a measurable benefit?

Say this basic hypothetical code,

```
import math

number = '5'
variable = math.ceil(float(number))
print(variable)
```

which would appear to run fine, was refactored, or condensed into

```
from math import ceil

print(ceil(float('5.1')))
```

Both programs run fine, without error, but why is the former much less common in production? The first code snippet appears easier to read and looks more simple. Is there a performance benefit that comes with the single line of code versus the elaborated form in the second part?

Comment: When it comes to performance, you can use the built-in timeit module, or memory profile your code to see the results yourself. As for the reason you might see one or the other, it will be highly dependent on the environment and the preference of the person doing the coding. Personally, I would use the former for readability, and if I needed to reuse the variables. I would use the latter (with comments in the code) if all I needed was to print a single result and save the memory allocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not too sure on the inner workings of a computer and how it runs code, but i believe the first one would run the tiniest bit slower because of the introduction of a new variable. I doubt it would be noticeable. But again, I know nothing about that, please inform me if I’m wrong and ill delete this.

The first has 77 bytes whereas the second is only 48 bytes, so there would be a slight improvement in the time it would take to run this.

Comment: This would be better as a comment than an answer. See [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: I do agree that the performance difference is negligible in the example given. With that said, write millions of these small inefficiencies into a large codebase and it will add up.